# knife_project in python

Tags: python, scripting, knife-tool

I am a blender noob trying to use bpy.ops.mesh.knife_project() in my script. It fails with the message:

> RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.mesh.knife_project.poll() expected a
>   view3d region & editmesh

Already tried [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43335/how-do-i-get-knife-project-operator-to-use-view-settings-within-the-operator) method. It fails with the same message

Here is the relevant part of my code. insulator is the active mesh object. knife is the curve object to be used as knife.

```
knife.select = True
insulator.select = True

override = context.copy()
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        override['area'] = area
        override['space'] = area.spaces[0]
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                override['region'] = region
                break
        break

bpy.ops.view3d.viewnumpad(override, type = 'BOTTOM', align_active = True)
bpy.ops.view3d.view_persportho(override)

#bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT', toggle = False)
#bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.knife_project(override, cut_through = True)
```

The view changes to bottom and orthographic view, but the script halts at knife_project.

The blender python reference gives very little information about this function.

Any ideas?

Comment: I couldn't get it to fully work, but after selecting, you need to set the active object (`bpy.context.scene.objects.active = insulator`) and set it to edit mode. However, I could only get it to work when the object to be cut was selected in the viewport *before* running the script. In general though, it is better to avoid `bpy.ops` see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops

Comment: I would love to avoid bpy.ops in this case, but was unable to find a bmesh alternative to knife_project. Do you know of one?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too knowledgeable in the bmesh area, all I was able to find was `bisect_edges`, here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39540/cut-bmesh-with-python

Answer (score 2):

You walked in right direction, but the code should be wrapped in operator execution method, register and call it from Operator Search using chosen view.

I've made this gist from operator_simple.py template, it works from object or edit mode with active object as target and other as knifes.
https://gist.github.com/Begalov/763688551b49004d92ef227ddd7694d6

[image]